# How to use ssh-copy-id on remote server?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, aws-ec2

I have an ec2 instance which I can connect using this command with the ssh_key.pem file I have.

```
ssh -i ssh_key.pem ec2-user@54.174.85.61
```

I am trying to use ssh-copy-id to add the public key I have on my local machine to remote ec2 instance.

```
ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_ed25519.pub ec2-user@54.174.85.61
```

output:

> /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed:
> ".ssh/id_ed25519.pub" /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in
> with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
> /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you
> are prompted now it is to install the new keys ec2-user@54.174.85.61:
> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

But, it is not working, I guess because I didn't provide any parameter of my private key to connect.

But, I am not able to see any such parameters in the help -h also.

Please suggest how to do so.

ssh-copy-id is not working as mentioned but I found one alternative.

I can connect to the remote machine using the pem file 3.pem

```
ssh -i 3.pem ec2-user@54.174.85.61
```

So, I tried below scp command.

```
scp -q -i 3.pem .ssh/id_ed25519.pub ec2-user@54.174.85.61:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now, this worked and I am able to login with my key generated.

```
ssh -i .ssh/id_ed25519 ec2-user@54.174.85.61
```

But, it replaces access to 3.pem, earlier key.
Because it replaces all the content in the authorized_keys file as I am just copying the file and it replacing the old file.

How to make sure, only append happens.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using publickey validation already (which from what I read you do) I would double check permission for both folders and files related to ssh public key that is
~/.ssh   this should be 0700
~/.ssh/authorized_keys  this should be 0600

Comment: but the scenario here, I have a linux machine locally where it has different public and pvt ssh keys. There is one more remote machine(ec2) which I connect with differetn pvt key. When I am trying to use ssh-copy-id, there is no option I saw to pass this different pvt key as parameter. I saw some -o parameter, but documentaion not good for that. So without that option, it is trying to use the main pvt key default one and getting this permission denied error. Can you suggest how to do in this case

Comment: [This is how you can add multiply keys for one user account on server you try to connect](https://serverfault.com/questions/221760/multiple-public-keys-for-one-user)

Comment: No, he is adding entries manually on the remote machine, which I am trying to achieve from ssh-copy-id

Comment: I tried scp instead of ssh_copy_id, can see the content added above and comment on that

Comment: if you added public key in correct format you should be able to use private key on that server

Answer (score 0):

Got solution, at this link: https://superuser.com/questions/1264012/how-to-ssh-copy-id-2nd-key-when-the-server-only-allows-publickey-authentication

```
ssh-copy-id -f -i ~/.ssh/dev_pub_key.pub -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o "IdentityFile ~/ssh_key.pem" $user@$server_name
```

Thank you all for helping on this